# How can I avoid any blocking when using Observable.FromEventPattern in Reactive Extensions for .NET?

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive, observable

I'm struggling with some concurrency issues in relation subscribing to an `Observable.FromEventPattern()` on the `TaskPoolScheduler`.

Let me illustrate with a code example:

```
var dataStore = new DataStore();

Observable.FromEventPattern<DataChangedEventArgs>(dataStore, nameof(dataStore.DataChanged))
    .SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
    .Select(x => x.EventArgs)
    .StartWith(new DataChangedEventArgs())
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(25))
    .Select(x => 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // Simulate long-running calculation.
        var result = 42;
        return result;
    })
    .ObserveOn(new SynchronizationContextScheduler(SynchronizationContext.Current))
    .Subscribe(result =>
    {
        // Do some interesting work with the result.
        // ...

        // Do something that makes the DataStore raise another event.
        dataStore.RaiseDataChangedEvent(); // <- DEADLOCK!
    });

dataStore.RaiseDataChangedEvent(); // <- Returns immediately, i.e. does NOT wait for long-running calculation.
dataStore.RaiseDataChangedEvent(); // <- Blocks while waiting for the previous long-running calculation to complete, then returns eventually.
```

My issue is that, when any new items are emitted by the original observable `Observable.FromEventPattern()` (i.e. when the `DataStore` object raises new `DataChanged` events), then they appear to be blocked waiting for the previous items to finish flowing through the entire pipeline.

Since the subscribing is done on the `TaskPoolScheduler` I had expected every new item emitted to simply spin up a new task, but actually, the source of the event instead seems to block on the event invocation if the pipeline is busy.

How can I accomplish a subscription that executes every new emitted item (raised event) on it's own task/thread, such that the source object never blocks on its internal `DataChangedEvent.Invoke()` call?

(Except of course the `Subscribe()` lambda which should execute on the UI thread - which is already the case.)

As a side-note: @jonstodle mentioned in the #rxnet Slack channel that the `TaskPoolScheduler` might have different semantics than what I assumed. Specifically he said it probably creates *one* task and does both the subscribing and the producing of values in an event loop inside of that one task. But if that's the case, then I find it a bit strange that the *first* event invocation doesn't block (since the second one does). Seems to me that if the task pool task doing the subscription is asynchronous enough that the souce doesn't have to block on the first invocation, there shouldn't be a need to make it block on the second call either?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue you're hitting is simply the way Rx works - each value produced in a normal Rx pipeline is, well pipelined, and only one value is processed at a time. If the source of a Rx pipeline, in your case the `FromEventPattern<DataChangedEventArgs>` produces values faster than the observer(s) handles them then they get queued in the pipeline.

The rule is that each observer in the pipeline will only process one value at a time. That happens for any scheduler, not just `TaskPoolScheduler`.

The way to make it work they way you want is quite simple - you create parallel pipelines and then merge the values back into a single pipeline.

Here's the change:

```
Observable
    .FromEventPattern<DataChangedEventArgs>(dataStore, nameof(dataStore.DataChanged))
    .SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
    .Select(x => x.EventArgs)
    .StartWith(new DataChangedEventArgs())
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(25))
    .SelectMany(x =>
        Observable.Start(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000); // Simulate long-running calculation.
            var result = 42;
            return result;
        }))
    .ObserveOn(new SynchronizationContextScheduler(SynchronizationContext.Current))
    .Subscribe(result =>
    {
        // Do some interesting work with the result.
        // ...

        // Do something that makes the DataStore raise another event.
        dataStore.RaiseDataChangedEvent();
    });
```

The `.SelectMany(x => Observable.Start(() =>` replaces the `.Select(x =>` allowing the values to being a new observable subscription which runs immediately and then it merges the values back into a single observable.

You may prefer to write it as the semantically identical `.Select(x => Observable.Start(() => ...)).Merge()`.

Here's a simple example that shows how this works:

```
var source = new Subject<int>();

source
    .SelectMany(x =>
        Observable.Start(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return x * 2;
        }))
    .Subscribe(result =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        source.OnNext(result);
        source.OnNext(result + 1);
    });

source.OnNext(1);
```

It produces:

```
2
4
6
14
12
8
10
24
28
30
26
16
20
22
18
48
50
56
52
58
60
62
54
32
34
46
44
40
42
```

Comment: Wow, fantastic answer, thanks! Both your explanation and your suggested fix make total sense.But there's one thing I don't quite get still - if the pipeline can only process one item at a time, why does the first event invocation *not* block? Or inversely, if the subsequent items get queued up as you say, why can't those items be put onto the queue for future processing while still returning control immediately and allowing the calling code to continue?

Comment: @DanielStolt - That would depend on the thread that the observable is processing on. This code, `Observable.Range(0, 10).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x)); Console.WriteLine("Done.");`,  is executed on the one thread so the numbers appear before the word `Done.`, but the code, `Observable.Range(0, 10).ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x)); Console.WriteLine("Done.");`, is pushed to a new thread so `Done.` appears in the middle.

Comment: @DanielStolt - Your code, right up to the `ObserveOn`, runs on the same thread as the event is raised on so it is synchronous.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, that's definitely not what I'm observing (pun intended). The **first** call to `DataChanged.Invoke()` inside of `DataStore` definitely returns immediately, even though the `Select()` delegate takes several seconds to complete. Only the **subsequent** calls block, until the first item has flowed all the way through the entire pipeline. I find this weirdly asymmetric.

Comment: @DanielStolt - I'd be interested to know if that behaviour changes if you were to remove the `.SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)`?

Comment: Yes, as expected, if I remove that, then the invocation runs completely synchronously, also on the first invocation, i.e. the `DataChanged.Invoke()` call blocks until the whole pipeline returns.

Comment: Nice answer. Shouldn't the comment `// <- DEADLOCK!` be removed though?